# Using has_key in array in rails from multi-level JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, multidimensional-array

I have a set of JSON data that has multiple levels of data. Snippet of the JSON (ignore the missing formatting please):

```
DATA SET A:
"interaction": {
   "author": {
      "username": "johndoe",
      "name": "John Doe"
   }
},
"gender": "male"

DATA SET B:
"interaction": {
   "author": {
      "name": "Jane Doe"
   }
},
"gender": "male"
```

In a single-level I can use:

```
if record.has_key?('gender')
```

and that will return a true/false value if the key is present.

If I try to seed data and the key isn't present, it will throw an error and stop seeding.

My question: How would I check to see if the "username" key exists. Data Set B, for example, doesn't have a username key and would throw an error, but I can't figure out how to modify the has_key() command to check for a few levels down.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to work around the `has_key` method and used a begin/rescue/end.

```
begin
  @data.username = record['interaction']['author']['username']
rescue
  @data.username = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility:

```
# where a and b are loaded from JSON
a = {
  'interaction' => {
    'author' => {
      'username' => 'johndoe',
      'name' => 'jd'
    }
  }
}
b = {
  'interaction' => {
    'author' => {
      'oijoijoij' => 'johndoe',
      'name' => 'jd'
    }
  }
}
class Hash
  def recursive_has_key?(key)
    has_key?(key) or values.any? { |v| v.is_a?(Hash) and v.recursive_has_key?(key) }
  end
end
puts a.recursive_has_key?('username')
puts b.recursive_has_key?('username')
```

Which outputs

```
$ ruby foo.rb 
true
false
```

Comment: Good approach, though not sure this would fully work in the event a key is duplicated somewhere and carries different values. Could build the function into the seed.rb file - so we're close.

Comment: Update: I'm not sure how to build that method into the seed.rb file. I tried adding it in as a method and it didn't like it being in the file and trying to call it. Any thoughts on how I can add it in?